# Entity Framework Code-First, MySQL and unicode support

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I'm using EF Code-First (EFCF) with MySQL to create my database using Migrations. The problem I'm having is with the character columns.

I'm not an expert in MySQL but from what I've been reading, in MySQL you can support Unicode in your tables at least in two ways:

1. Making it the default for the entire table: `CREATE TABLE mytable (...) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`
2. Making each specific column support Unicode: `CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 VARCHAR(10)  CHARSET utf8, OtherColNotUnicode VARCHAR(5), ...);` (note that MySQL doesn't have NVARCHAR)

As it turns out, EFCF Migrations create the tables and columns without Unicode support by default and I could not find a way to override that or annotate the properties in my model, basically forcing it to use either option *1* or *2*.

How can I correct this problem? Preferably I'd like to set it on a column by column basis but I'd probably live with a whole table default if necessary.

If it helps anything, I'm using EF 5.0, MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity v 6.6.4.0.

Comment: I am not familiar with EF Code-Frist at all, but are you saying ti actually specifies the charset and collations, or is it going off the default collation and charset set for the database. You can also define these at the database level. So if perhaps you do that, you will automatically get all tables/columns with utf-8.

Comment: @MikeBrant well, that's my question, right? How can I make EFCF create the tables or the columns with Unicode support. Maybe using attributes, maybe some setting in the EF DbContext? Or maybe it's a bug/limitation in the MySQL EF component.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that you set the default charset and collation at the database level.  If EFCF is not explicitly definining charset and collation (which my guess is thatt it doesn't), you will automatically have all newly created tables/column have unicode support.  Of course this may be overkill, in that typically only a handful of columns (that are used for data that is acutally displayed) would need such support, in which case, I would just build the appropriate `ALTER TABLE` directives into your migrations.

Comment: Adding to what Mike says and related to code first entity framework (where the database is created for you and you don't really have access to do this type of thing that I know of) you can set the default charset for new databases on your mysql server. See http://makandracards.com/makandra/2529-show-and-change-mysql-default-character-set